# Why is the module tk not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with my small login window. I'd like to program a small login window for one of my programs with a button to check the input. The program is working fine till my computer wants to enable the button:

TypeError: 'Tk' object is not callable

Why is this like that? What is wrong? Are all commands right?

```
    import tkinter
import os

def login():
    c= tkinter.Entry.get(input1)
    if c == "admin":
        a = tkinter.Entry.get(input2)
        if a == "1234":
            os.system('SpambotV1')
        else:
            print("hi")
    else:
        print("Cancled")


# Hauptprogramm

login=tkinter.Tk()
login.title("login")
login.config(background="blue")

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="/Users/Hannes/Desktop/Spambot/Roboter.gif")
w = tkinter.Label(login,image=photo)
w.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=0,pady=0)

#Loginframe

frame1=tkinter.Frame(login)
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

#loginlabel

text1=tkinter.Label(frame1,text="Please login", bg="red")
text1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

#Input1

input1=tkinter.Entry(frame1,width=12)
input1.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)


#text 2
text2=tkinter.Label(frame1,text="Username",bg="red")
text2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

#text 3
text3=tkinter.Label(frame1,text="Password",bg="red")
text3.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

#Entry 2

input2=tkinter.Entry(frame1,width=12)
input2.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

#knopf
knopf=tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Login",bg="red",command=login())
knopf.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
```

Comment: You have a function called `login` and your window variable is also called `login`. Rename one of the two.

Comment: BTW, it's a common practice to do `import tkinter as tk`. That way, you can use short references like `tk.Tk()`, `tk.Label` etc.

Answer (score 2):

By creating a function called login and then creating a variable with the same name, you cause conflict in your code. Try renaming it to `submit` or something else. You specified the command of the button to be `login()` but python doesn't remember the login function, it only remembers the window variable you created, which is a Tk object, and that isn't callable. So what you should do is change the name of the `login()` function to `submit()`.

Also remember to change:

```
knopf=tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Login",bg="red",command=login())
```

to:

```
knopf=tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Login",bg="red",command=submit)
```

and remove the brackets in as @PM 2Ring suggested
EDIT:
let's give some credit to @Rawing for spotting it too. Sorry. I didn't see the comment